# How to set Burn.exe FileVersion and ProductVersion differently?

Tags: wix, version, bootstrapper, burn

Our finally generated Burn.exe file got same versions for FileVersion and ProductVersion. However, version scheme followed in our team suggests ProductVersion as 2015.0.

As FileVersion is coming from Version attribute of Bundle element, Is there any way to set ProductVersion property of Burn.exe file different from FileVersion?
[image]

Thanks